# Select a range of rows from every n rows from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2880 observations in my `data.frame`. I have to create a new `data.frame` in which, I have to select rows from 25-77 from every 96 selected rows.

```
df.new = df[seq(25, nrow(df), 77), ] # extract from 25 to 77
```

The above code extracts only row number 25 to 77 but I want every row from 25 to 77 in every 96 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a vector of indeces with which subset the dataframe.

```
idx <- rep(25:77, times = nrow(df)/96) + 96*rep(0:29, each = 77-25+1)
df[idx, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recycling technique to extract these rows :

```
from = 25
to = 77
n = 96

df.new <- df[rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(from - 1, to - from + 1, n - to))), ]
```

To explain for this example it will work as :

```
length(rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(24, 53, 19))) #returns
#[1] 96
```

In these 96 values, value 25-77 are `TRUE` and rest of them are `FALSE` which we can verify by :

```
which(rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(24, 53, 19)))
# [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
#[23] 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68
#[45] 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

Now this vector is recycled for all the remaining rows in the dataframe.

Comment: Recycling is very useful in situations like these, didn't come to mind! Thanks Ronak

Comment: Also: `i = logical(n)`; `i[from:to] = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

First, define a `Group` variable, with values `1` to `30`, each value repeating 96 times.  Then define `RowWithinGroup` and filter as required.  Finally, undo the changes introduced to do the filtering.

```
df <- tibble(X=rnorm(2880)) %>% 
        add_column(Group=rep(1:96, each=30)) %>% 
        group_by(Group) %>% 
        mutate(RowWithinGroup=row_number()) %>% 
        filter(RowWithinGroup >= 25 & RowWithinGroup <= 77) %>% 
        select(-Group, -RowWithinGroup) %>% 
        ungroup()
```

Welcome to SO.  This question may not have been asked in this exact form before, but the proinciples required have been rerefenced in many, many questions and answers,

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner `base` solution.

```
lapply(split(df, cut(1:nrow(df), nrow(df)/96, F)), `[`, 25:77, )
```

***Note:*** *Nothing after the last comma*

---

The code above returns a list. To combine all data together, just pass the result above into

```
do.call(rbind, ...)
```